# getting marginal from the joint distributiion function

Tags: probability

Given joint probability distribution function $F(x,y)= 1-e^{-x}-e^{-y}+e^{-x-y}$ for $x>0,y>0$. 
How do we get the marginal distribution functions?

I thought of taking the derivative, but after taken the derivative with respect to x, the resulting function has a y term.

Comment: Distribution function of $X$ is $F_X(x)=F(x,\infty)$ and similarly for $Y$.

Comment: Is there an upper bound on $x$ and $y$. I posted an answer to what you have written, but the PDF you have is nonnormalizable, so it can't be a real PDF and there's no good answer, I think

Comment: @CadeReinberger The F in question is a distribution function, not a density. You might want to edit your response below since OP accepted that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remark: This response is not my own. Since it's been a day now and OP has not unaccepted this answer, on the recommendation of StubbornAtom I have edited this response to include the correct response of iljusch. This response belongs to iljusch, and OP should really, it seems, accept that response, whence I can delete this one**

Assuming that by "joint probability distribution" you mean the joint cumulative distribution function (CDF) defined by
$$
F(x,y) := \mathbb P(X\le x, Y\le y),
$$
you obtain the marginal CDFs by
$$
F_X(x) = \mathbb P(X\le x)
=
\lim_{y\to\infty} \mathbb P(X\le x, Y\le y)
=
\lim_{y\to\infty} F(x,y)
=
1-e^{-x}
$$
and similarly $F_Y(y) = 1-e^{-y}$. If you want to obtain the marginal probability densities, you just differentiate the CDFs and get $f_X(x) = e^{-x},\ f_Y(y) = e^{-y}$.

In your specific case, things can be obtained in an easier way, since the joint CDF factorizes (is a product of two marginal CDFs):
$$
F(x,y)
=
1-e^{-x}-e^{-y}+e^{-x-y}
=
(1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-y}),
$$
therefore $F_X(x) = (1-e^{-x})$ and $F_Y(y) = 1-e^{-y}$ can be seen directly.

Comment: I think "joint probability distribution" is supposed to mean "joint cumulative distribution function" and not, as you seem to assume, a joint probabilty density.

Comment: In hindsight, that's probably right. Probably OP will recognize this and accept your answer, although, I think it might be wise to leave my response up, just in case similar questions might arise. But, overall, that's almost certainly what "joint probability distribution" is supposed to mean

Comment: In particular, I should note, I can't delete this until OP revokes the accept

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "joint probability distribution" you mean the joint cumulative distribution function (CDF) defined by
$$
F(x,y) := \mathbb P(X\le x, Y\le y),
$$
you obtain the marginal CDFs by
$$
F_X(x) = \mathbb P(X\le x)
=
\lim_{y\to\infty} \mathbb P(X\le x, Y\le y)
=
\lim_{y\to\infty} F(x,y)
=
1-e^{-x}
$$
and similarly $F_Y(y) = 1-e^{-y}$. If you want to obtain the marginal probability densities, you just differentiate the CDFs and get $f_X(x) = e^{-x},\ f_Y(y) = e^{-y}$.

In your specific case, things can be obtained in an easier way, since the joint CDF factorizes (is a product of two marginal CDFs):
$$
F(x,y)
=
1-e^{-x}-e^{-y}+e^{-x-y}
=
(1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-y}),
$$
therefore $F_X(x) = (1-e^{-x})$ and $F_Y(y) = 1-e^{-y}$ can be seen directly.